# Open subgroup of $SO(3)$

Tags: group-theory, harmonic-analysis

Does $SO(3)$ have an open nontrivial subgroup?(Group $SO(3)$ with usual matrices product, is all $3\times 3$ matrices whose determinant is 1 and for every element $A\in SO(3)$ we have $A^tA=AA^t=I_3$ and also let it's norm be a operator norm, that's, norm of linear mapping $A:R^3\rightarrow R^3$ which induced the topology on $SO(3)$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that open subgroups are also closed (since all cosets are open, any coset, being the complement of the union of the other cosets, is also closed). So we'd be talking about a subgroup that is open and closed. But $SO(3)$ is connected; in fact it is a quotient space $S^3/\{1, -1\}$ of the unit quaternions, which is itself connected. Thus there are no nontrivial open subgroups.

Comment: May I ask how "open subgroups are also closed" is used in the rest of your argument?

Comment: A nonempty topological space $X$ is connected if it cannot be expressed be expressed as the disjoint union $A \cup B$ of two nonempty open subsets; here $A$ and $B$ are complements of each other. Since the complement of an open set is closed, it would mean $A$ is both open and closed. Thus connectedness rules out the existence of nonempty proper subsets that are both open and closed. Does that help?

Comment: I understand we need connectedness to say that the neighborhood of identity of SO(3) is the whole group, but why do we need this neighborhood to be closed?

Comment: Under the condition of connectedness, openness and closedness of the subgroup force it to be the whole thing, is what the argument is getting at.

Comment: I mean, if you're still stuck on this point, I can rephrase so as not to mention closed sets at all. Let $G_0$ be the open nontrivial subgroup (nontrivial = proper) and let $\{gG_0\}$ be the collection of cosets. Since left multiplication by any $g$ is a homeomorphism, each of these cosets is open. Now let $A = G_0$, and let $B$ be the union of all other cosets. Then both $A$ and $B$ are open, and $A$ and $B$ are also disjoint, and finally both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty ($B$ is nonempty because $A = G_0$ is a proper subgroup). These facts put together would make the group $G$ be disconnected.

Comment: I don't understand why it is needed to mention open sets are also closed. I think this fact is really needed since this was a hint I was giving to solve this problem. However as you said, being open and connected seems enough.